# KeepAlive still fire onMounted every time visit component

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, keep-alive

My project made from parent layout and nest layout nest many child components I used `<router-view>` and nest `<router-view>` too when I applied `KeepAlive` to one of child component and  debug with console log the `onActivated` and `onDeactivated` both fire correctly

```
onActivated(() => {
  console.log('OnActived fired');
})

onDeactivated(() => {
  console.log('onDeactivated fired');
})

onMounted(() => {
  console.log('onMounted fired');
})
```

But at the same time I navigated away from the component to another route and then return to it, the `onMounted` alway fired every time too I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a route for KeepAlive package switching

Comment: I have import component and assigned to component also not work

Comment: You can provide more code details

Comment: I fixed my mistaken call keepalive not close to <router-view> thank